# Translating C# code with delegate to Java, to use with Android

Tags: c#, java, android

I'm in the process of diving into Android development. Most of the projects I was involved with, were in C#. Delegates were elements of C# I did use very often, I've used also stuff like passing data using class that extends EventArgs or properties with set and get. With my programming knowledge I think I will be able to get started with Android development pretty smoothly. The thing is I have completly no idea how to approach an implementing mechanism similar to C# delagte in Java.

Below I present some exemplary class that works in C# just fine and contains some elements of C# language that I would like to use in my future Android projects. Can someone provide me with a translation of this code? I would prefer that 'cos working with my own example and its conversion would allow me to catch it all faster. Also, any valuable resources on the topic (not only delegates but genereal topic of converting C# into Java) would be apreciated.

**CountdownTimer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SampleDelegateApp
{
    public class CountdownTimer
    {
        Timer tmrTicks = new Timer();
        int secondsLeft = 0;
        int numberOfSecondsToCountdown = 0;

        public bool IsWorking
        {
            get { return tmrTicks.Enabled; }
        }

        public CountdownTimer(int seconds)
        {
            if (secondsLeft < 0) secondsLeft = 0; 
            numberOfSecondsToCountdown = seconds;
            secondsLeft = seconds;

            tmrTicks.Interval = 1000;
            tmrTicks.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrTicks_Tick);
            tmrTicks.Enabled = false;
        }

        void tmrTicks_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            secondsLeft--;
            if (secondsLeft >= 1) 
                WhenCountdownTimerTick(new CountdownTimerEventArgs(secondsLeft, numberOfSecondsToCountdown, false));
            else
            {
                Stop();
                WhenCountdownTimerTick(new CountdownTimerEventArgs(secondsLeft, numberOfSecondsToCountdown, true));
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Stop();
            secondsLeft = numberOfSecondsToCountdown;
            if (secondsLeft < 0) secondsLeft = 0;
            WhenCountdownTimerTick(new CountdownTimerEventArgs(secondsLeft, numberOfSecondsToCountdown, false));
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            tmrTicks.Enabled = false;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            if (secondsLeft <= 0)
            {
                secondsLeft = 0;
                WhenCountdownTimerTick(new CountdownTimerEventArgs(secondsLeft, numberOfSecondsToCountdown, true));
            }
            else
            {
                tmrTicks.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        public delegate void CountdownTimerTickEventHandler(object sender, CountdownTimerEventArgs ea);

        public event CountdownTimerTickEventHandler CountdownTimerTick;

        protected virtual void WhenCountdownTimerTick(CountdownTimerEventArgs ea)
        {
            if (CountdownTimerTick != null)
            {
                CountdownTimerTick(this, ea);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CountdownTimerEventArgs : EventArgs
    {

        public string timeString = "";
        public float procentOfTimeLeft = 0.0f;
        public bool countdownFinished = false;

        public CountdownTimerEventArgs(int secondsLeft, int SecondsToCountdown, bool isfinished)
        {
            countdownFinished = isfinished;
            timeString = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", secondsLeft / 60, secondsLeft % 60);
        }
    }
}
```

**frmTest.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SampleDelegateApp
{
    public partial class frmTest : Form
    {
        CountdownTimer ctmrTest;

        public frmTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ctmrTest = new CountdownTimer(-44);
            ctmrTest.CountdownTimerTick += new CountdownTimer.CountdownTimerTickEventHandler(ctmrTest_CountdownTimerTick); 
        }

        void ctmrTest_CountdownTimerTick(object sender, CountdownTimerEventArgs ea)
        {
            lblTimer.Text = ea.timeString;
            if (ea.countdownFinished) countdownEnd();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ctmrTest.Reset();
            ctmrTest.Start();
        }

        void countdownEnd()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Finish");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apparently used some words in my question that made it all unclear and/or persons who tried to help me completly missunderstood my needs as for this question. Putting word "delegate" here and there made it even more complexed. After one more question asked in other way i got my answer that made me able to answer my question:

[How to achieve c# event behavior in java (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262539/how-to-achieve-following-c-sharp-behaviour-in-java-android)

I'm not saying that code below is up to the best coding standards, and example shown here got any use in real life project, but this is exactly what i was looking for. Below working example:

**tester.java**

```
public class tester{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test test1 = new test(); 
        test1.start();
    }
}
```

**test.java**

```
public class test implements CountdownTextTickListener {

    public test() { }

    public void start() {
        CountdownText ctx = new CountdownText(100);
        ctx.setListener(this);
        ctx.Start();
    }

    @Override
    public void CountdownTextTickEventFired(Object sender, 
                        CountdownTextTickEventArgs eventArgs) {
            System.out.println(eventArgs.TimeString);
            if(eventArgs.isStopped) System.out.println("- END -");
    }
}
```

**CountdownTextTickListener.java**

```
public interface CountdownTextTickListener {
     void CountdownTextTickEventFired(Object sender, CountdownTextTickEventArgs eventArgs);
}
```

**CountdownTextTickEventArgs.java**

```
public class CountdownTextTickEventArgs {

    public String TimeString = "";
    public boolean isStopped = false;

    public CountdownTextTickEventArgs(int seconds, boolean isStoppedState) {
        TimeString = String.format("%02d:%02d",seconds/60, seconds % 60);
        isStopped = isStoppedState;
    }

}
```

**CountdownText.java**

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class CountdownText {

    Timer tmrTicks = new Timer();
    int secondsLeft = 0;
    int numberOfSecondsToCountdown = 0;
    boolean isWorking = false;
    private CountdownTextTickListener listener = null;

    public boolean getIsWorking(){
        return isWorking;
    }

    public CountdownText(int seconds) {
        if (secondsLeft < 0) secondsLeft = 0; 
        numberOfSecondsToCountdown = seconds;
        secondsLeft = seconds;
    }

    void startTimer() {
        isWorking = true;
        fireEvent(secondsLeft, false);
        tmrTicks = new Timer();
        tmrTicks.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                tickTimer();
            }
        }, 1000, 1000); 
    }

    private void stopTimer() {
        isWorking = false;
        tmrTicks.cancel();
    }

    private void tickTimer() {
         secondsLeft--;
         if (secondsLeft >= 1) 
         {
             fireEvent(secondsLeft, false);
         }
         else
         {
             Stop();
             fireEvent(secondsLeft, true);
         }
    }

    public void Reset() {
        Stop();
        secondsLeft = numberOfSecondsToCountdown;
        fireEvent(secondsLeft, false);
    }

    public void Stop() {
        stopTimer();
    }

    public void Start() {
        if (secondsLeft <= 0)
        {
            secondsLeft = 0;
            fireEvent(secondsLeft, true);
        }
        else
        {
            startTimer();
        }
    }

    protected void fireEvent(int seconds, boolean isStoppedState) {
        if (listener != null) {
            Object sender = this; 
            CountdownTextTickEventArgs eventArgs = new CountdownTextTickEventArgs(seconds, isStoppedState);
            listener.CountdownTextTickEventFired(sender, eventArgs);
        }
    }

    public void setListener(CountdownTextTickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all about the observer pattern really. In .NET this has been made easy with delegates and stuff, in Java you must implement it by hand, using interfaces for the handlers and plain objects for the args. Look it up, you will find plenty of info.

Comment: Well if anyone would come with helping hand i probly will be forced to, but as i said in my post it would be best if i got it converted/translateed. Not that im lazy (or so so so lazy), just from experience i know such way is best for me if it comes to learning new stuff.

Comment: @MoreThanChaos. I whole heartedly suggest you take Mario's advice and do a search for Java observer pattern, to implement your requirement using interfaces and argument objects. There are many straightforward examples out there and I think once you see them you will see how simple they are to use.

Comment: @MoreThanChaos When you understand the pattern, go look if the Android SDKs don't have anything in them to implement this pattern for your apps.

Comment: @paulkayuk sure sure guys, but the reason ive spent like about hour carving this post and example is clearly stated in my post contents. Maybe its hard to process for you guys and hard to understand but i fo really need what i asked about in my question, my way of learning stuff is peculiar. Well i still hope somone will understand  it and help me. And that akk is to help to understand the pattern so i can proceed with Android.

Comment: @Mario De Schaepmeester, look on above ive wrote to paulkayuk, you guys seem like you just readed topic, seen source code and nothing else.

Comment: @MoreThanChaos the downvote was unnecessary, and you're the one who's not listening. There is no way of "translating" delegates into Java. That's a .NET thing. If you want to "learn", learn the underlying design patterns, that's the only way you will be able to re-write it in any OO language.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester I didnt asked for transalting delegate itself, but whole code i presented, to see how this code, I understand and Im familiar with, will would look like in java. Call me lazy, or whatever you like, i asked exactly what i was intent to ask and your answer wasn't too much of help. And there are plenty ways of "learnining" and my might seem strange and you can not agree with it but believe me or not it works for me best.

Comment: @MoreThanChaos sorry to tell you that you're on the wrong address then on StackOverflow, see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). I don't think any one here will do what you want, and they shouldn't...

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, there are actually ways to get your C# code to work in Android. I suggest looking at [Mono for Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) if your situation allows you to do your work in C#. Not only do you get to leave your code in C#, but you can also port it over to MonoTouch for iOS and .NET 4.5 for Windows Phone more easily. If not, I can't help you, but I'm sure someone more knowledgeable will.

Comment: Sure, if not 1k $ you got to spent on licence, all would be great