# How to achieve c# event behavior in java (Android)

Tags: c#, java, android

when i was programming in c# i was making very often use of events. Now I would like to achieve something similar in Java. I know both languages are diffrent and there are some diffrences in implementing such mechanism. Well to give better picture maybe i will describe a little what i want to get, because i might confuse some of terminology:

**MyClass** contains code that handles launching **MyEvent** and some code that in certain situations launches that event.

**MyEventArgs** is class that transports data from **MyClass** and is sent along with event launch, so function that handles **MyEvent** has some additional information about state of **MyClass** instance.

And there is **MyApp** class that in main method contains instance of **MyClass** and code handling **MyEvent** and when event is raised inside **MyClass** certain actions are performed in code that listens to **MyEvent**.

If it's still unclear, what i mean to achieve is exactly like c# mechanism that is behind button click, just instead of button there is my class, there are my event arguments instead of mouse event args and there is behaviour designed by me instead of click.

I've tried to google some answers to my problem and for example i found sites like:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/observer-design-pattern-java-example.html http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-03/01-qa-0315-happyevent.html

And either im just lost and I'm looking in bad places/using bad keywords, or what more possible i can't understand anything out of these examples/i can't transform them to work in way I need.

What im asking for, is some example, or atleast some draft of code handling such mechanism with use of **MyClass,**  **MyEvent,**  **MyEventArgs,** names, pointing code i should use in my class to raise event and some sample use of class and handling of event in Main method, so it would help me wrap my mind around this problem.

**==========Edit========**

Maybe there are some things like that avaliable for android developers? As my goal is to get to get into mobile apps development after i dust off java.

**==========Edit========**

If anyone still interested, here is some sample code, it doesn't use names i metioned, just shows in general what im looking for:

And is there no exact solution, maybe somone would suggest something similar to thing im looking for?

**frmTest.cs**

```
namespace SampleApp
{
    public partial class frmTest : Form
    {
        CountdownTimer ctmrTest;

        public frmTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ctmrTest = new CountdownTimer(100);
            ctmrTest.CountdownTimerTick += new CountdownTimer.CountdownTimerTickEventHandler(ctmrTest_CountdownTimerTick); 
        }

        void ctmrTest_CountdownTimerTick(object sender, CountdownTimerEventArgs ea)
        {
            lblTimer.Text = ea.timeString;
            if (ea.countdownFinished) countdownEnd();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ctmrTest.Reset();
            ctmrTest.Start();
        }

        void countdownEnd()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Finish");
        }
    }
}
```

**CountdownTimer.cs**

```
namespace SampleApp
{
    public class CountdownTimer
    {
        Timer tmrTicks = new Timer();
        int secondsLeft = 0;
        int numberOfSecondsToCountdown = 0;

        public bool IsWorking
        {
            get { return tmrTicks.Enabled; }
        }

        public CountdownTimer(int seconds)
        {
            ...
        }

        void tmrTicks_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ...
            WhenCountdownTimerTick(new CountdownTimerEventArgs(secondsLeft, numberOfSecondsToCountdown, true));
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            ...
            WhenCountdownTimerTick(new CountdownTimerEventArgs(secondsLeft, numberOfSecondsToCountdown, false));
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            tmrTicks.Enabled = false;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            ,,,
        }

        public delegate void CountdownTimerTickEventHandler(object sender, CountdownTimerEventArgs ea);

        public event CountdownTimerTickEventHandler CountdownTimerTick;

        protected virtual void WhenCountdownTimerTick(CountdownTimerEventArgs ea)
        {
            if (CountdownTimerTick != null)
            {
                CountdownTimerTick(this, ea);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CountdownTimerEventArgs.cs**

```
namespace SampleApp
{
    public class CountdownTimerEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string timeString = "";
        public bool countdownFinished = false;

        public CountdownTimerEventArgs(int secondsLeft, int SecondsToCountdown, bool isfinished)
        {
            countdownFinished = isfinished;
            timeString = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", secondsLeft / 60, secondsLeft % 60);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be easy to understand your question if you post the behavior as implemented in C#

Comment: @Suresh: He's talking about the standard C# event stuff (`public event void StuffChanged(object src, EventArgs args)` and `this.StuffChanged(this, someEventArgs);`.  Java has no direct analogue; C#'s event model uses delegates rather pervasively, and Java doesn't have delegates.  Instead, Java uses observable interfaces and an `addListener` function.

Comment: Yeah, except Java seems tightly bound to GUI. Maybe Java 8!

Comment: @trashgod I would really prefer some draft that makes use of names i mentioned, i seem not to deal well with code samples in case of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand you correctly (i'm just starting learning C#), the normal way to do it in Java is to use the observer pattern (listener pattern):

You create a listener interface with a method to be called when your event happens. 
That method can take some event-arguments and a sender as parameter, if you like. 
For example:

```
public interface MyListener { // This is probably your MyEvent
    void myEventFired(Object sender, MyEventArgs eventArgs);
}

public class MyEventArgs {
    ...something...
}
```

A class which is to respond to your kind of event, needs to implement the above interface.
(see an example a little below (MyListeningClass))

Ok, so then you need a class (or more classes) which fires your event: **MyClass**. 
Usually **MyClass** has some way for other classes, who wants to respond to **MyClass**' event, to register 
themselves with **MyClass**. (Or more precisely, register themselves with a specific object of **MyClass**). This allows the **MyClass**-object to know which other objects it should inform about when the event happens.

This is usually done by creating a method called "add[ListenerName]" in the class firing the event - in this case "**addMyListener**" in **MyClass**.
To make this example simpler, let's just assume there can *only ever be one* listener, so we will call it "**setMyListener**" instead:

```
public class MyClass {

    private MyListener listener = null;

    // This is a method which sometimes fires an event, by calling the fireEvent() method below
    public void doSomething() {
        ...
        if (something) {
            // Let's say the event happens if "something" is true. 
            // So now we "fire the event". What "firing the event" means, 
            // is just to call the "myEventFired" method in the listener.
            fireEvent();
        }
        ...

    }

    // this is called from the method above to fire the event - i.e. to tell the listener that the event has happened
    protected void fireEvent() {
        if (listener != null) {
            Object sender = this; 
            MyEventArgs eventArgs = new MyEventArgs(...something...);
            listener.myEventFired(sender, eventArgs);
        }
    }

    // This method is called by the listener, to register itself as listener on this object.
    // MyClass remembers the listener in the "listener" instance variable, so that 
    // when the event happens at some later point in time, it knows which object it  
    // has to tell it to.
    public void setMyListener(MyListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

*(To support more than one listener, just have a list of listeners `List<MyListener> listeners` instead of the `MyListener listener` instance variable, and create an addListener and removeListener method instead of the setListener method. In the Android API they usually only allow one listener, so i thought i would show that version)*

So now we just need the class which wants to listen for the event. I.e. the class implementing the **MyListener** interface. (This class is thus a listener). A simple example:

```
public class MyListeningClass implements MyListener {

    public MyListeningClass() {
        MyClass myClass = ...get the MyClass object from somewhere...;
        myClass.setMyListener(this);
    }

    // this is called by MyClass when the event occurs
    public void myEventFired(Object sender, MyEventArgs eventArgs) {
        System.out.println("EVENT HAPPENED!");
        System.out.println("Sender is: "+sender);
        System.out.println("MyEventArgs are: "+eventArgs);
    }    
}
```

*(Of course you don't actually have to create the interface if you don't want to. You could of course just hardcode the MyListeningClass in MyClass instead, but it's better style to use interfaces, to decouple MyClass and MyListeningClass from each other. And it'll also be more extendable later, to allow other classes than MyListeningClass to listen for the events too.)*

There are many examples of this in the Java API. For example SWING makes heavy use of listeners - for example for button-clicks, as you mention. And of course the Android API too.

I'll see if i can find some examples of this later, but it's very late and i'm very tired, so maybe tomorrow :D (and fix any spelling mistakes :D). Hope it helped a bit.

**To Recap:**

- **MyClass** (the class producing the events) needs some way to tell other classes about that the event has happened, when the event happens.
  It does that by calling a method in these classes when the event happens.
- For **MyClass** to be able to call a method in these other classes, they have to implement some interface.
- The classes which want to be told when the event happens, needs a way to tell **MyClass** that they want to 
  be told about it. This is the reason we need the **MyClass.setMyListener** method. 
  *(or if we had allowed more than one listener: the **MyClass.addMyListener** method)*

(So there is nothing magical about this. It's just simple method calling.)

---

*(Note that, a listener interface is usually named "[name of the event]Listener". So instead of "MyListener" i should have called it "MyEventListener", according to the naming convention, if we say that the event is called "MyEvent". But for this post i think it looked too long and less simple.* UPDATE: *Now that i think about it, you actually usually omit "Event" from the name, so "MyListener" is right. For example if you have an event you call "OnClickEvent", you call the interface "OnClickListener".)*

Comment: Wow, it does really work for me, and explanation is really well served (finally something that I've been able to crunch). I just wonder what is the deal with multiple listeners (list). I still have some doubts like with that list of listeners... and some other stuff that more precisely will come out, as i guess, in process (like for example class launching 3 diffrent types of events or program using 2 instaces of MyClass), hopefully i will be able to transoform code in way to make it work as I like, anyway BIG THANKS, i got to get more familiar with this and i will eventually ask some question

Comment: Thank you for the nice words and i'm glad it helped. :) You're free to ask. Maybe i can extend the answer to include a list implementation, but it's just that addMyListener(MyListener) adds the listener to the list, removeMyListener(MyListener) removes it 
from the list and fireEvent() loops through all listeners in the list and calls the listener-method in each of them. 
Another thing: If you want something similar to delegates in C#, you can use anonymous classes in java.

Comment: By the way, maybe you could rename the title of this question to something like "How to achieve c# event behavior in java (Android)", so the title describes the question a bit better and so that the question will show up in searches for other people having the same problem you had?

Comment: sure, already done. Posting good questions isnt my strong side. I asked similar question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112796/translating-c-sharp-code-with-delegate-to-java-to-use-with-android After being misunderstood i decided to ask it other way, more precisely, this time i did succeed. Btw this system is pretty flexible/open and you surely could do that edit by yourself

Comment: how to achieve this in java public class MyClass{

        public enum State {
            Closed,
            Opened,
            FullyOpened
        }
        public event Action<State> StateChanged;

        void setState(State state){
            StateChanged(state);
        }
        
        void clearAction(Action action){
            action();
        }
    }

Comment: You do it just like in the answer above. 

Create an interface for the listener, with one method that takes State as parameter (for example). You could call it StateChangedListener. 
And then create the addStateChangedListener(StateChangedListener listener) and removeStateChangedListener(...) methods in MyClass.
When MyClass.setState(...) is called (the event is fired), call the method in all the added listeners. (when calling the listeners, give the new State to them as parameter.)

Comment: I like it too, thks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be to use `Google Web Toolkit (GWT)`. You can define event handlers for `GWT Widgets` in much the same way as using Visual Studio/C#.

Eclipse even has a built in window builder plugin.

Comment: i basically think about java cause i want to get into andorid development, ive decided to dust off and get along with java first